# Como diferenciar tipos de telefone

Tags: algoritmo, brasil

Tenho o seguinte problema: o cliente vai me enviar um número de telefone e eu preciso diferenciar se é fixo ou celular, alguém conhece algumas regras que distinguem bem os dois grupos?

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54615/discussion-on-question-by-reiksiel-como-diferenciar-tipos-de-telefone)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

O [**Plano de Numeração**](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plano_de_Numera%C3%A7%C3%A3o) é o modo de organização dos números dos serviços de telecomunicações de uso público. A tabela abaixo tem a relação entre as faixas numéricas de telefone fixo e celular, baseado nisso creio que fique fácil resolver seu problema.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fonte: [Teleco](http://www.teleco.com.br/num.asp)

Answer (score 30):

## Estrutura do Sistema Telefónico Brasileiro

Os números essencialmente podem ter 4 porções:

- Prefixo do país (dois dígitos):

  Código de chamada país: [**+55**](https://www.google.pt/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=brazil%20country%20calling%20code)
- Prefixo da operadora (dois dígitos):

  <sup>12 - [CTBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algar_Telecom)</sup>
  <sup>14 - [Brasil Telecom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brasil_Telecom)</sup>
  <sup>15 - [Telefónica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telef%C3%B3nica)</sup>
  <sup>21 - [Embratel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embratel)</sup>
  <sup>23 - [Intelig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelig_Telecom)</sup>
  <sup>25 - [GVT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Village_Telecom)</sup>
  <sup>31 - [Oi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oi_(telecommunications))</sup>
  <sup>41 - [TIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telecom_Italia_Mobile)</sup>
- Prefixo geográfico (dois dígitos): <sup>[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_dialling_codes_in_Brazil)</sup>

  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- Número de telefone nos formatos:

  ```
  NNNN-NNNN
  9NNNN-NNNN
  ```

Além disso, existem outros números com uma nomenclatura especial, os números de utilidade publica que contém apenas 3 digitos.

## Tipos de números

Existem apenas dois tipos de números, fixos ou móveis, distinguidos entre si pelo primeiro digito:

- 2 a 5 são números fixos (linha terrestre)
- 6 a 9 são números móveis (telemóvel)

## Pseudocódigo

Com base nos dados em cima expostos, o algoritmo teria que funcionar dentro dos seguintes moldes:

1. Verificar se tem mais que três dígitos para determinar se é um número de utilidade publica.

   Se for de utilidade publica, terminamos aqui e agimos em conformidade.
2. Verificar se número começa por `+55` para determinar se tem o código de chamada do país.

   Se tiver o código de chamada do país, vamos remover o mesmo do número e continuar com a verificação.
3. Verificar se tem pelo menos 12 dígitos.

   Se não tiver 12 ou mais dígitos, é inválido, terminamos aqui e agimos em conformidade.
4. Verificar se tem 13 dígitos.

   Se tiver 13 digito, é numero móvel de São Paulo, terminamos aqui e agimos em conformidade.
5. Apurar se fixo ou móvel.

   Chegando aqui temos que ter 12 dígitos, como tal, vamos pegar no 5º digito e verificar se o mesmo está no grupo (2~5) ou no grupo (6~9), terminamos a operação e agimos em conformidade.
6. Opcional:

   Partir os 12 dígitos em porções para identificar onde se encontra o mesmo:

   ```
   2 dígitos - Operadora
   2 dígitos - Área geográfica
   4 dígitos - Primeira parte do número
   4 dígitos - Segunda parte do número
   ```

## Diagrama

O fluxo da informação com base no que apuramos até ao momento pode ser apresentado da seguinte forma:

[image: Diagrama - Fluxo de informação]

## Código

Colocando em prática todo este exercício, vamos implementar a solução com JavaScript:

```js
document.getElementById("validar").onclick = function() {

  var continuar = true,
    numero = document.getElementById('numero').value;

  // Verificar se vazio
  if (numero.length === 0) {
    alert("Brincalhão, preenche lá o número!");
    continuar = false;
  }

  // Verificar se número é de utilidade publica
  if (numero.length === 3) {
    alert("Número de utilidade publica");
    continuar = false;
  }

  // Verificar se tem código do país para retirar
  if (continuar && numero.substring(0, 3) === "+55") {
    numero = numero.substring(3);
  }

  // Verificar se menos que 12 digitos
  if (continuar && numero.length < 12) {
    alert("Número inválido, por favor introduza Cod. Operadora + Cod. Area + Numero");
    continuar = false;
  }

  // Verificar se contém 13 digitos
  if (continuar && numero.length === 13) {
    alert("Número móvel");
    continuar = false;
  }

  // Verificar se o 5º digito
  var digitoControlo = numero.charAt(4);

  if (continuar) {

    if (digitoControlo >= 2 && digitoControlo <= 5) {
      alert("Número fixo");
    } else if (digitoControlo >= 6 && digitoControlo <= 9) {
      alert("Número móvel");
    } else {
      alert("Número especial");
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="numero" name="numero" />
  <button id="validar">validar</button>
</form>
```

**Notas:**

Existem outras verificações a realizar, como o caso de não existirem letras no lugar de números, mas tais verificações não fazem parte do apuramento do número e devem ser tidas em consideração antes do mesmo ser iniciado.

Algumas das verificações podem nem ser requeridas, vai da implementação de cada um, motivo o qual as mesmas estão separadas, tornando-se modulares.

---

<sup>Eu sou Português de Portugal, se falhei algum detalhe sobre a estrutura do "vosso" sistema telefónico, deixem um comentário, terei todo o gosto em atualizar a resposta.</sup>

Comment: Ótima resposta, só senti falta de uma referência mais direta que corroborasse sua afirmação que "Se tiver 13 digito, é numero móvel de São Paulo, terminamos aqui e agimos em conformidade." (afinal, essa foi a motivação da recompensa...) Digo "mais direta", pois essa informação está [meio escondida](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_Brazil#Ninth_digit_for_mobile_numbers) no artigo da Wikipedia para o qual sua resposta linka. Mas está lá, acompanhada de citações, de modo que considero a referência válida. +1 e recompensa concedida!

Comment: @mgibsonbr Tenho uma revisão para o código de exemplo na pergunta, aproveitarei para ser mais transparente na questão de São Paulo ao fazer a edição!

Answer (score 5):

Atualmente pela anatel somente os números de telefone que iniciem com 6,7,8,9 são números de celular. [Você pode fazer um regex para interpretar isso](http://goncin.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/validando-numeros-de-telefone-com-expressoes-regulares/). Lembrando que é somente o número do telefone não incluindo ddd.

Comment: conforme o comentario que fiz na pergunta, eu sei usar regex, não é esse o problema, preciso de um "algoritmo" ou uma regra que eu possa separar os dois grupos.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o novo serviço de Lookup do Twillo.

https://www.twilio.com/lookup

Com o modulo pago ele te da o tipo do número (móvel ou fixo) e a operadora também.

```
curl -X GET https://lookups.twilio.com/v1/PhoneNumbers/55-11-5525-6325\
    -d "Type=carrier"
    -u "{AccountSid}:{AuthToken}"

{
    "country_code": "BR",
    "phone_number": "+551155256325",
    "national_format": "(11) 5525-6325",
    "url": "https://lookups.twilio.com/v1/PhoneNumber/+551155256325",
    "carrier": {
        "type": "landline",
        "error_code": null,
        "mobile_network_code": null,
        "mobile_country_code": null,
        "name": "Vivo"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Após estudar a resposta do [Zuul](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/223/zuul) e analisar este artigo da [Anatel](http://www.anatel.gov.br/Portal/exibirPortalNivelDois.do?codItemCanal=1794), eu adaptei a solução dele (em **JavaScript**) para as duas linguagens de programação principais que uso: **Java** e **Object Pascal**. Criando as respectivas classes. E o código foi testado e está funcionando para números com e sem o **NONO DÍGITO**.

No entanto, fiz algumas alterações, para aceitar números especiais, como *0300*, *0500*, *0800*, *0900*, *3003*, *4003* e *4004*. Corrigi também alguns bugs quando o usuário informa números com zeros a mais, por exemplo: (OP) *041* (DDD) *87* (NUM) *9999-9999*, ou: (OP) *41* (DDD) *087* (NUM) *9999-9999*.

Abaixo o código das classes.

Em **Java**:

```
/*
        Telefone - Retorna o tipo de um número de telefone (fixo, móvel, público etc.)

        Baseado neste tópico:

        . https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14343/como-diferenciar-tipos-de-telefone

        Autores:

        . Silvio Clécio - github.com/silvioprog
*/

package br.com.duallsistemas.telefone;

/**
 * Created by silvioprog on 06/04/2015.
 */
public class Telefone {
    private String numero;
    private String ddd;
    private String codOperadora;

    public Telefone(String codOperadora, String ddd, String numero) {
        this.codOperadora = apenasNumeros(apenasString(codOperadora));
        this.ddd = apenasNumeros(apenasString(ddd));
        setNumero(numero);
    }

    public Telefone(String codOperadora, String ddd) {
        this(codOperadora, ddd, "");
    }

    public Telefone() {
        this("", "");
    }

    private boolean inRange(int num, int min, int max) {
        return num >= min && num <= max;
    }

    private boolean numeroEspecial() {
        return numero.startsWith("0300") || numero.startsWith("0500") || numero.startsWith("0800") ||
                numero.startsWith("0900") || numero.startsWith("3003") || numero.startsWith("4003") ||
                numero.startsWith("4004");
    }

    private boolean temNonoDigito() {
        Integer i = Integer.parseInt(numero.substring(0, 2));
        return inRange(i, 11, 19) || inRange(i, 21, 24) || i == 27 || i == 28 || inRange(i, 91, 99);
    }

    protected String apenasNumeros(String s) {
        if (s == null)
            return "";
        String result = "";
        for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
            if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
                result += c;
        }
        return result;
    }

    protected String apenasString(String s) {
        if (s == null)
            return "";
        s = s.trim();
        if (s.equals(""))
            return "";
        return s;
    }

    public String getCodOperadora() {
        return codOperadora;
    }

    public String getDdd() {
        return ddd;
    }

    public TipoTelefone obtemTipo() {
        int len = numero.length();
        if (len <= 2)
            return TipoTelefone.INVALIDO;
        if (len == 3)
            return TipoTelefone.PUBLICO;
        if (len < 12) {
            if (numeroEspecial())
                return TipoTelefone.ESPECIAL;
            else
                return TipoTelefone.INVALIDO;
        }
        if (len == 13)
            return TipoTelefone.MOVEL;
        char digito;
        if (len == 15)
            digito = numero.charAt(7);
        else
            digito = numero.charAt(4);
        if (digito >= '2' && digito <= '5')
            return TipoTelefone.FIXO;
        if (digito >= '6' && digito <= '9')
            return TipoTelefone.MOVEL;
        return TipoTelefone.ESPECIAL;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return String.valueOf(obtemTipo());
    }

    public String getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    public void setNumero(String numero) {
        numero = apenasString(numero);
        if (numero.equals(""))
            return;
        if (numero.startsWith("+55"))
            numero = numero.substring(3);
        this.numero = apenasNumeros(numero);
        int len = this.numero.length();
        if (len == 8 ) {
            if (!numeroEspecial())
                this.numero = codOperadora + ddd + this.numero;
        } else if (len == 9)
            this.numero = codOperadora + ddd + this.numero;
        else if (len == 10)
            this.numero = codOperadora + this.numero;
        else if (len == 11 || len == 14) {
            if (!numeroEspecial() && this.numero.substring(0, 1).equals("0")) {
                this.numero = this.numero.substring(1);
                this.numero = codOperadora + this.numero;
            } else if (temNonoDigito())
                this.numero = codOperadora + this.numero;
        }
    }
}
```

Exemplo de uso (Obs: os números usados no exemplo são fictícios):

```
package br.com.duallsistemas;

import br.com.duallsistemas.telefone.Telefone;

public class Main {

    public static void imprime(Telefone tel, String numero) {
        tel.setNumero(numero);
        System.out.println("NUMERO REAL: " + tel.getNumero() + ", TIPO: " + tel.getDescricao());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Telefone tel = new Telefone("41", "65");
        System.out.println("INTRODUZA O NUMERO DO SEGUINTE FORMATO: COD. OPERADORA + COD. AREA + NUMERO");
        System.out.println("=======");
        System.out.println();
        // inválidos
        imprime(tel, "12");
        imprime(tel, "+55 41 (99) 999-9999");
        System.out.println();
        // público
        imprime(tel, "190");
        System.out.println();
        // especial
        imprime(tel, "0300 313 4701");
        imprime(tel, "0500 313 4701");
        imprime(tel, "0800 729 0722");
        imprime(tel, "0900 313 4701");
        imprime(tel, "3003 3030");
        imprime(tel, "4003 3030");
        imprime(tel, "4004 3030");
        System.out.println();
        // fixo
        imprime(tel, "3549-5589");
        imprime(tel, "(87) 3549-5589");
        System.out.println();
        // movel
        imprime(tel, "9985-0997");
        imprime(tel, "(87) 9985-0997");
        imprime(tel, "31 (87) 9985-0997");
        imprime(tel, "+55 31 (87) 9985-0997");
        System.out.println();
        // movel SP
        imprime(tel, "9 9985-0997");
        imprime(tel, "(11) 9 9985-0997");
        imprime(tel, "31 (11) 9 9985-0997");
        imprime(tel, "031 (11) 9 9985-0997");
    }
}
```

Em **Object Pascal** (compatível com **Free Pascal 2.6.4+** e **Delphi 7+**):

```
(*

  TTelefone - Retorna o tipo de um número de telefone (fixo, móvel, público etc.)

  Baseado neste tópico:

    . https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14343/como-diferenciar-tipos-de-telefone

  Autores:

    . Silvio Clécio - github.com/silvioprog

*)

unit Telefone;

{$IFDEF FPC}
{$mode objfpc}{$H+}
{$ENDIF}

interface

uses
  SysUtils;

type

  { TTipoTelefone }

  TTipoTelefone = (ttInvalido, ttPublico, ttFixo, ttMovel, ttEspecial);

  { TTelefone }

  TTelefone = class(TObject)
  private
    FNumero: string;
    FDdd: string;
    FCodOperadora: string;
    function GetCodOperadora: string;
    function GetDdd: string;
    function GetDescricao: string;
    function GetTipo: TTipoTelefone;
    procedure SetNumero(ANumero: string);
    function TemNonoDigito: Boolean;
    function NumeroEspecial: Boolean;
  public
    constructor Create(const ACodOperadora, ADdd, ANumero: string); overload; virtual;
    constructor Create(const ACodOperadora, ADdd: string); overload; virtual;
    constructor Create; overload; virtual;
    function ApenasNumeros(const S: string): string;
    function ApenasString(const S: string): string;
    property CodOperadora: string read GetCodOperadora;
    property Ddd: string read GetDdd;
    property Numero: string read FNumero write SetNumero;
    property Descricao: string read GetDescricao;
    property Tipo: TTipoTelefone read GetTipo;
  end;

const
  DESC_TELEFONE: array[TTipoTelefone] of string = (
    'INVALIDO', 'PUBLICO', 'FIXO', 'MOVEL', 'ESPECIAL'
    );

implementation

{ TTelefone }

constructor TTelefone.Create(const ACodOperadora, ADdd, ANumero: string);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FCodOperadora := ApenasNumeros(ApenasString(ACodOperadora));
  FDdd := ApenasNumeros(ApenasString(ADdd));
  SetNumero(ANumero);
end;

constructor TTelefone.Create(const ACodOperadora, ADdd: string);
begin
  Create(ACodOperadora, ADdd, '');
end;

constructor TTelefone.Create;
begin
  Create('', '');
end;

function TTelefone.TemNonoDigito: Boolean;
var
  I, E: Integer;
begin
  Val(Copy(FNumero, 1, 2), I, E);
  Result := E = 0;
  if Result then
    case I of
      11..19, 21..24, 27, 28, 91..99: Result := True;
      else
        Result := False;
    end;
end;

function TTelefone.NumeroEspecial: Boolean;
var
  N: ShortString;
begin
  N := Copy(FNumero, 1, 4);
  Result := (N = '0300') or (N = '0500') or (N = '0800') or (N = '0900') or
    (N = '3003') or (N = '4003') or (N = '4004');
end;

function TTelefone.ApenasNumeros(const S: string): string;
var
  C: Char;
{$IFNDEF FPC}
  I: Integer;
{$ENDIF}
begin
  Result := '';
{$IFDEF FPC}
  for C in S do
    if (C >= '0') and (C <= '9') then
      Result += C;
{$ELSE}
  for I := 1 to Length(S) do
  begin
    C := S[I];
    if (C >= '0') and (C <= '9') then
      Result := Result + C;
  end;
{$ENDIF}
end;

function TTelefone.ApenasString(const S: string): string;
begin
  Result := Trim(S);
end;

function TTelefone.GetCodOperadora: string;
begin
  Result := FCodOperadora;
end;

function TTelefone.GetDdd: string;
begin
  Result := FDdd;
end;

function TTelefone.GetTipo: TTipoTelefone;
var
  D: Byte;
  L
{$IFNDEF FPC}
  , E
{$ENDIF}
  : Integer;
begin
  L := Length(FNumero);
{$IFDEF FPC}
  if L <= 2 then
    Exit(ttInvalido);
  if L = 3 then
    Exit(ttPublico);
  if L < 12 then
  begin
    if NumeroEspecial then
      Exit(ttEspecial)
    else
      Exit(ttInvalido);
  end;
  if L = 13 then
    Exit(ttMovel);
  if L = 15 then
    Val(FNumero[8], D)
  else
    Val(FNumero[5], D);
  if (D >= 2) and (D <= 5) then
    Exit(ttFixo);
  if (D >= 6) and (D <= 9) then
    Exit(ttMovel);
  Result := ttEspecial;
{$ELSE}
  if L <= 2 then
    Result := ttInvalido
  else if L = 3 then
    Result := ttPublico
  else if L < 12 then
  begin
    if NumeroEspecial then
      Result := ttEspecial
    else
      Result := ttInvalido;
  end
  else if L = 13 then
    Result := ttMovel
  else
  begin
    if L = 15 then
      Val(FNumero[8], D, E)
    else
      Val(FNumero[5], D, E);
    if (D >= 2) and (D <= 5) then
      Result := ttFixo
    else if (D >= 6) and (D <= 9) then
      Result := ttMovel
    else
      Result := ttEspecial;
  end;
{$ENDIF}
end;

function TTelefone.GetDescricao: string;
begin
  Result := DESC_TELEFONE[GetTipo];
end;

procedure TTelefone.SetNumero(ANumero: string);
var
  L: Integer;
begin
  ANumero := ApenasString(ANumero);
  if ANumero = '' then
    Exit;
  if Copy(ANumero, 1, 3) = '+55' then
    ANumero := Copy(ANumero, 4, MaxInt);
  FNumero := ApenasNumeros(ANumero);
  L := Length(FNumero);
  if L = 8 then
  begin
    if not NumeroEspecial then
      FNumero := FCodOperadora + FDdd + FNumero;
  end else if L = 9 then
    FNumero := FCodOperadora + FDdd + FNumero
  else if L = 10 then
    FNumero := FCodOperadora + FNumero
  else if (L = 11) or (L = 14) then
    if (not NumeroEspecial) and (Copy(FNumero, 1, 1) = '0') then
    begin
      Delete(FNumero, 1, 1);
      FNumero := FCodOperadora + FNumero;
    end
    else if TemNonoDigito then
      FNumero := FCodOperadora + FNumero;
end;

end.
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
program test;

{$IFDEF FPC}
{$mode objfpc}{$H+}
{$ENDIF}

uses
  Telefone;

  procedure imprime(tel: TTelefone; const num: string);
  begin
    tel.Numero := num;
    WriteLn('NUMERO REAL: ', tel.Numero, ', TIPO: ', tel.Descricao);
  end;

var
  tel: TTelefone;
begin
  tel := TTelefone.Create('41', '65');
  try
    WriteLn('INTRODUZA O NUMERO DO SEGUINTE FORMATO: COD. OPERADORA + COD. AREA + NUMERO');
    WriteLn('=======');
    WriteLn;
    // inválidos
    imprime(tel, '12');
    imprime(tel, '+55 41 (99) 999-9999');
    WriteLn;
    // público
    imprime(tel, '190');
    WriteLn;
    // especial
    imprime(tel, '0300 313 4701');
    imprime(tel, '0500 313 4701');
    imprime(tel, '0800 729 0722');
    imprime(tel, '0900 313 4701');
    imprime(tel, '3003 3030');
    imprime(tel, '4003 3030');
    imprime(tel, '4004 3030');
    WriteLn;
    // fixo
    imprime(tel, '3549-5589');
    imprime(tel, '(87) 3549-5589');
    imprime(tel, '31 (87) 3549-5589');
    WriteLn;
    // movel
    imprime(tel, '9985-0997');
    imprime(tel, '(87) 9985-0997');
    imprime(tel, '31 (87) 9985-0997');
    WriteLn;
    // movel SP
    imprime(tel, '9 9985-0997');
    imprime(tel, '(11) 9 9985-0997');
    imprime(tel, '31 (11) 9 9985-0997');
    imprime(tel, '031 (11) 9 9985-0997');
    imprime(tel, '+55 31 (11) 9 9985-0997');
    imprime(tel, '+55 031 (11) 9 9985-0997');
  finally
    tel.Free;
    ReadLn;
  end;
end.
```

Este código está funcionando perfeitamente bem em [um aplicativo em produção](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=br.com.duallsistemas.duallsms), espero que seja útil para os demais colegas! =)

Comment: +1 Muito bom! O _problema_ é que agora vou ter que me esforçar mais na minha resposta para resolver os "bugs" encontrados :P Se mais algum do que referiste, avisa-me para aprimorar a versão de JavaScript.

Comment: Beleza @Zuul, e obrigado pela ajuda, pois sem ela eu não teria conseguido fazer estas classes. =) Você pode atualizar a versão JS usando essa versão que passei em Java, pois os códigos são bastante compatíveis. Qualquer dúvida posso te ajudar, pois futuramente vou precisar da versão JS também, para fazer validações em páginas web.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se sua dúvida ainda esta na sua cabeça, mas encontrei uma solução.

Achei um site, e nele contem uma lista das Operadoras, DDD's e Range de Prefixos em cada Estado, sendo ela SME e/ou SMP. Pelo que notei, de tempos em tempos eles soltam uma atualização desta lista, mas eu baixei as completas, tanto SME quanto SME, e as coloquei em uma tabela. Segue abaixo o link de onde baixei esses arquivos.
[http://sistemas.anatel.gov.br/sapn/Default.asp?SISQSmodulo=18096&SISQSsistema=288](http://sistemas.anatel.gov.br/sapn/ArquivosABR/faixaSME.asp?SISQSmodulo=18098)

Depois disso, fiz uma logica simples no sql. Acredito que seja mais facil mostrar do que explicar.

```
DECLARE
         @Telefone  VARCHAR(12) = 'ddXXXXXXXX' --<-- COLOQUE O TELEFONE AQUI
        ,@DDD       VARCHAR(2)
        ,@Prefixo   VARCHAR(5)
        ,@Final     INT

        SET @DDD        = LEFT(@Telefone, 2)
        SET @Prefixo    = LEFT(RIGHT(@Telefone, 8), 4)
        SET @Final      = RIGHT(@Telefone, 4)

    SELECT 
         Telefone = CONVERT(VARCHAR, DDD) + CONVERT(VARCHAR, Prefixo) + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @Final)
        ,Nome
        ,DDD
        ,Prefixo
        ,Final = @Final
    FROM Operadora 
    WHERE DDD = @DDD
      AND Prefixo LIKE '%' + @Prefixo
      AND @Final BETWEEN Inicial AND Final
```

Eu apenas troquei os Nomes dos campos do mailing para nomes utilizáveis em tabelas, mas acredito que ficou bem intuitivo.

Neste script, caso ele tenha algum resultado no fim, é porque é um celular e ele vai colocar o nono digito caso no telefone ele não venha. Caso não traga nenhum resultado no fim, o numero é um numero fixo.

Answer (score 1):

Vi muitas respostas, mas depois de algumas horas analisando tudo que temos sobre telefones brasileiros, criei uma função pra validar os telefones, incluindo:

- Validação de números repetidos
- Validação de quantidade de caracteres (se é 10 ou 11 números, fora o caracteres que não conta)
- Validação de celular (9º digito) se o numero tiver 11 dígitos
- Validação de DDDs (semente DDDs válidos) - Obrigado @renatoargh
- Validar se o numero é telefone mesmo ou do tipo rádio (se o numero começa entre 2 e 5, ou 7) - Valido somente após 2017, se a ANATEL fizer tudo direitinho

A ANATEL ainda não implementou tudo, mas quando alguém ver isto e já estiver em 2017 ou depois (olha só estou falando com alguém do futuro haha) é só excluir a linha que verifica o ano, que está referenciada no código.

vejam um exemplo em funcionamento:[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/83zopn51/1/)

Segue também o Gist pra quem queira ajudar a aprimorar o código ou relatar erros: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/jonathangoncalves/7bdec924e9bd2bdf353d6b7520820b62)

Obrigado tambem ao @Leandro Curioso, pois baseei meu código no seu.

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow. Muito boa resposta!