# Como validar número de telefone fixo e celular jQuery Validator?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validação

Preciso de um método de validação de telefone fixo e celular com o plug-in jQuery Validator.

A diferenciação de números de fixo para celular é importante para validar o envio de SMS.

Comment: Não sei porque deram 1 ponto negativo para o post. Fiz com intenção de ajudar. E a pessoa que diminuiu a nota nem disse o porque.

Comment: Também não sei por que o downvote (e o voto pra fechar), mas não seria o caso de postar isso como pergunta? Citando [o blog do stack overflow](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) "é ok responder sua própria pergunta desde que você finja que está participando do Jeopardy" :P Faça uma pergunta do tipo "como validar telefone fixo e celular?", e responda sua própria pergunta, em vez de uma única postagem onde não há pergunta alguma.

Comment: @LeandroCurioso transforme sua resposta em pergunta + resposta, deixando a pergunta no lugar de pergunta e a resposta no lugar da resposta, e daí estará tudo ok. Você deve seguir o padrão pergunta-resposta mesmo se você mesmo está fazendo os dois. Entendeu?

Comment: Certo! obrigado pelas dicas.

Comment: Boa dica do Math e o mgibsonbr. Aconselho nas próximas vezes que for fazer o mesmo, que é algo que apreciamos, que faça uma pergunta com cara de pergunta real e dê a resposta para ela. As pessoas estão votando para fechar a pergunta. Porque na forma que ela está, talvez só você consegue respondê-la porque sabe a resposta. Sua intenção é muito boa, só faltou manter a pergunta de forma mais clara. Quem sabe outra pessoa responda também e talvez te dê uma forma melhor de fazer o mesmo.

Comment: Esse plugin pra jQUery é exatamente o que você está procurando. Ele é uma extensão do jQuery Validator
http://rods.la/validador-de-telefone/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pela experiência em desenvolvimento web é muito comum ver que vários formulários que validam telefone fixo ou celular apenas contemplam a quantidade minima e máxima de caracteres, mas de fato não há uma verificação mais consistente em diferenciar um do outro. Muitas vezes é preciso enviar um SMS e o número de celular também é mal validado.

Para os desenvolvedores que utilizam o plug-in [jQuery Validator](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Segue abaixo dois métodos para que deixar o banco de dados mais integro e auxiliar na validação.

```
//Celular
jQuery.validator.addMethod('celular', function (value, element) {
    value = value.replace("(","");
    value = value.replace(")", "");
    value = value.replace("-", "");
    value = value.replace(" ", "").trim();
    if (value == '0000000000') {
        return (this.optional(element) || false);
    } else if (value == '00000000000') {
        return (this.optional(element) || false);
    } 
    if (["00", "01", "02", "03", , "04", , "05", , "06", , "07", , "08", "09", "10"].indexOf(value.substring(0, 2)) != -1) {
        return (this.optional(element) || false);
    }
    if (value.length < 10 || value.length > 11) {
        return (this.optional(element) || false);
    }
    if (["6", "7", "8", "9"].indexOf(value.substring(2, 3)) == -1) {
        return (this.optional(element) || false);
    }
    return (this.optional(element) || true);
}, 'Informe um celular válido'); 

 //Telefone fixo
 jQuery.validator.addMethod('telefone', function (value, element) {
        value = value.replace("(", "");
        value = value.replace(")", "");
        value = value.replace("-", "");
        value = value.replace(" ", "").trim();
        if (value == '0000000000') {
            return (this.optional(element) || false);
        } else if (value == '00000000000') {
            return (this.optional(element) || false);
        }
        if (["00", "01", "02", "03", , "04", , "05", , "06", , "07", , "08", "09", "10"].indexOf(value.substring(0, 2)) != -1) {
            return (this.optional(element) || false);
        }
        if (value.length < 10 || value.length > 11) {
            return (this.optional(element) || false);
        }
        if (["1", "2", "3", "4","5"].indexOf(value.substring(2, 3)) == -1) {
            return (this.optional(element) || false);
        }
        return (this.optional(element) || true);
    }, 'Informe um telefone válido');
```

Para utilização basta adicionar os métodos no seu script  e adicionar dentro da classe do input **(celular ou telefone)** ou caso deseje fazer a validação pelo método do plug-in  utilize **(telefone:true ou celular:true)**

Fazendo um adendo, a criação desses métodos foi inspirado na pergunta desse[link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14343/como-diferenciar-tipos-de-telefone/14346#14346).

Comment: Você pode incluir a [lista de DDDs válidos](https://github.com/gammasoft/brasil/blob/c0d04de0afc5843e4dcc64223a3b26d56a7192b7/lib/dadosUtils.js#L57-L94) para tornar sua validação ainda mais top.

Comment: O post ficaria mais claro se você enumerar no seu post os critérios usados para a diferenciação dos dois.

Comment: Ficou legal a validação, porém em vários locais o prefixo já não serve mais como validação de fixo ou celular. Por exemplo em SP tem celulares iniciando com prefixo 3!

Comment: é possível formatar ele ainda no input? ex: você passa 2188888888 e ele fica 21 8888 8888?

Answer (score 7):

depois de algumas horas analisando tudo que temos sobre telefones brasileiros, criei uma função pra validar os telefones, incluindo:

- Validação de números repetidos
- Validação de quantidade de caracteres (se é 10 ou 11 números, fora o caracteres que não conta)
- Validação de celular (9º digito) se o numero tiver 11 dígitos
- Validação de DDDs (semente DDDs válidos) - Obrigado @renatoargh
- Validar se o numero é telefone mesmo ou do tipo rádio (se o numero começa entre 2 e 5, ou 7) - Valido somente após 2017, se a ANATEL fizer tudo direitinho

A ANATEL ainda não implementou tudo, mas quando alguém ver isto e já estiver em 2017 ou depois (olha só estou falando com alguém do futuro haha) é só excluir a linha que verifica o ano, que está referenciada no código.

vejam um exemplo em funcionamento:[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/83zopn51/1/)

Segue também o Gist pra quem queira ajudar a aprimorar o código ou relatar erros: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/jonathangoncalves/7bdec924e9bd2bdf353d6b7520820b62)

Obrigado tambem ao @Leandro Curioso, pois baseei meu código no seu.

Comment: Função muito boa! Grato, homem do passado! Hahaha

Answer (score 2):

No final escolhe de usar [cleave.js](https://nosir.github.io/cleave.js/) e [regex para DDD](https://regexr.com/4bjc0). Cleave.js é um formatter bem moderno e facil de usar, que usa a biblioteca [Phonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) do google, mas ele não valida o DDD. Juntos com esse regex, vcs estão garantidos.

Eu criei esse regex baseado [na lista na wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discagem_direta_a_dist%C3%A2ncia)

```
^0?(1[1-9]|2[12478]|3[1-8]|4[1-9]|5[13-5]|6[1-9]|7[13-5]|7[79]|8[1-9]|9[1-9])
```