# Validação de numeros de celular com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validação

Existe alguma biblioteca que que valide o numero digitado pelo usuário?

Exemplo:

Se o usuário digitar (11)11111-1111 ou (22)2222-2222 e assim por diante, se digitar algo parecido, ele mostra que o telefone é inválido.

Existe alguma biblioteca com isso ou algum script onde eu possa trabalhar em cima?

Comment: Se você quer validar apenas no frontend, a tag PHP é desnecessária

Comment: você pode dá uma olhada nessa resposta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15126/26133