# Validação Campo Telefone

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pessoal preciso de uma ajuda de vocês.

Eu tenho uma mascará de telefone, que valida os campos 00000 11111 2222 3333 em sequencia.

```
 $('body').on('focus', '.celular', function () {
        var maskBehavior = function (val) {
            return val.replace(/\D/g, '').length === 11 ? '(00) 00000-0000' : '(00) 0000-00009';
        },
        options = {
            onKeyPress: function (val, e, field, options) {
                field.mask(maskBehavior.apply({}, arguments), options);

                if (field[0].value.length >= 14) {
                    var val = field[0].value.replace(/\D/g, '');
                    var intRegex = /[0-9 -()+]+$/;
                    if (/\d\d(\d)\1{7,8}/.test(val)) {
                        field[0].value = '';
                        notif({
                            msg: "<b>Atenção!</b> Este número está invalido!",
                            type: "error",
                            position: "center"
                        });
                    }
                }
            },
            clearIfNotMatch: true
        };
        $(this).mask(maskBehavior, options);
    });
```

Só que não estou conseguindo fazer ela validar esta sequencia 123456789 etc...

Alguém poderia me ajudar com isto?

Comment: [Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15126/5043) tem uma resposta muito boa sobre isso. Ela não te ajuda?

Comment: Não seria melhor fazer isso através de um regex? 
^\([0-9]{2}\)[0-9]{9}$ valida qualquer String no formato (DDD)Numero, incluindo os parênteses. Se você quiser validar um telefone Fixo, tem que comecar com 3, então seria ^\([0-9]{2}\)3[0-9]{7}$ e se for um telefone Celular começa com 9, então, ^\([0-9]{2}\)9[7-9][0-9]{7}$

Comment: @MarcosdeAndrade Como ficaria isso no regex? só substituir o valor que está em intRegex ?

Comment: @bio vou testar esta sua validação

Comment: O site da mozilla tem uma excelente referência sobre [Expressões Regulares](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), sugiro dar uma olhada. Sugiro também olhar o site [Regexr.com](https://regexr.com/) para validar suas regex, ele é excelente e tem umas referências muito boas na parte lateral.

Comment: @MarcosdeAndrade, acho que o AP está tentando validar um número inválido. Isso é, números que o usuário colocam como `(11) 1111-11111`. Infelizmente a regex que ele está usando não valida `(12) 3456-7890`, por exemplo. Acho que é isso, não?

Comment: @bio é isso mesmo, a sequencia de (11) 1111-11111 está verificando, o que não verifica é a sequencia de '(12) 3456-7890'

Comment: Ele está digitando o traço? A regex que escrevi não utiliza o traço, então não iria validar mesmo. 
Deixa eu entender o problema, você quer validar numeros telefones fixo E celular, Só Fixo ou Só celular? Se você quiser validar FIXO e CELULAR ao mesmo tempo, a regex tem que utilizar a expressão OR, ai é mais difícil de montar.

Comment: @MarcosdeAndrade Eu preciso que ele valide os dois porque se eu colocar a sequencia (01) 2345-6789 é fixo se eu colocar (01) 23456-7890 é celular só que as duas estão invalidas, deu pra entender o que estou querendo dizer?

Comment: Se você não for digitar o traço, utilize a regex ^\([0-9]{2}\)((3[0-9]{7})|(9[0-9]{8}))$

Se você for digitar o traço, utilize a regex ^\([0-9]{2}\)((3[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})|(9[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{5}))$

Comment: @MarcosdeAndrade esse regex ficaria assim?

var intRegex = /^([0-9]{2})((3[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})|(9[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{5}))$/; ou está errado? desculpe a pergunta não entendo muito sobre regex

Comment: Coloquei a regex logo acima do seu comentário. Estou fazendo um post  com a resposta. Como você está digitando uma String ele tem de ter aspas duplas começando e terminando, ou você digita direto no New RegExp(regex)

Comment: @MarcosdeAndrade Ok, vou ficar aguardando se post, cara muito obrigado pela sua ajuda

Answer (score 6):

Se você quiser validar um número, utilize uma Expressão Regular. O site da mozilla apresenta um [excelente artigo](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) sobre o tema, e o site [Regexr](https://regexr.com/) é ótimo para validar as expressões regulares.

No seu caso, se você for digitar o número com os parênteses e os traços, a expressão ficará

```
^\\([0-9]{2}\\)((3[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})|(9[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{5}))$
```

**Explicando:**

- O simbolo **^** indica o começo de uma String, e **$** indica o final de uma String. Isso quer dizer que não podem haver espaços em branco no começo ou no final da sua String. Ou você pode limpar a mesma utilizando uma chamada à função TRIM, ou você pode tirar o ^ e $
- \\( e \\) representam o especificamente a entrada do caractere ( e ). Utiliza-se a \ porque ela "escapa" o caractere ao invés de fazer ele ter sua função normal
- O símbolo - não precisa ser escapado com \ porque ele não possui outra função nas expressões regulares.
- [0-9]{2}  aceita dois de qualquer valor **em sequência** entre 0 e 9 (portanto, de 00 a 99)
- ( (Expressao) | (Expressao) ) Representa um OR Lógico, onde ele valida uma expressão OU outra, ou AMBAS.

**Se você for digitar sem os traços, a expressão será**

```
^\\([0-9]{2}\\)((3[0-9]{7})|(9[0-9]{8}))$
```

Acredito que, em ambos os casos, você pode atribuir a expressão regular a uma variável e inicializar um RegExp, ou iniciar direto através de uma passagem de atributo ao RegExp

```
var expressao = '^\\([0-9]{2}\\)((3[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})|(9[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{5}))$';
var regex = new RegExp(expressao);
```

OU

```
var regex = new RegExp('^\\([0-9]{2}\\)((3[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})|(9[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{5}))$');
```

Depois de criar a expressão regular você pode valida-la utilizando o método match que o regex possui.

```
var telefone = '(31)3233-4343';
var regex = new RegExp('^\\([0-9]{2}\\)((3[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})|(9[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{5}))$');
regex.test(telefone);
```

Em forma de função:

```
function validPhone (phone) {
    var regex = new RegExp('^\\([0-9]{2}\\)((3[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})|(9[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{5}))$');
    return regex.test(phone);
}

validPhone('(31)3534-2323'); //Valido
validPhone('(31)9923-23288'); //Valido
validPhone('(31)9923-3288'); //Invalido
validPhone('(31)2323-5443'); //Invalido
```

**Alternativamente**, você pode utilizar uma biblioteca que aplique uma mascara diretamente na view de forma reativa (assim como react, angular e vue, por exemplo, possuem aplicações) e o usuário só digitaria os numeros; ele seria armazenado sem os caracteres no seu banco ou estrutura de dados, o que facilitaria sua manipulação, e o numero seria formatado automaticamente somente quando apresentado à view (situação ideal).

Exemplo: 319938-42838 seria formatado para (31)9938-42838.

**Edit: Para validar um DDD entre 11 e 99:**

```
var telefone = '(31)9923-99288';
var regex = new RegExp('^\\(((1[1-9])|([2-9][0-9]))\\)((3[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})|(9[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{5}))$'); 
if (regex.test(telefone)) { 
    console.log("Válido");
}
else console.log("Inválido");
```

Você pode testar online através [dessa ferramenta](http://www.webtoolkitonline.com/javascript-tester.html).

**Edit:** Você está utilizando o Jquery Mask Plugin e, nele, está limpando o código dos parênteses e traços utilizados pelo usuário, e aplicando a mascara diretamente pela quantidade de números que o usuário digitou. Portanto, a Regex não vai funcionar porque está verificando se existem traços ou parênteses.

Para funcionar dessa forma, você pode utilizar o seguinte método:

```
function validatePhone (phone) {
    var regex = new RegExp('^((1[1-9])|([2-9][0-9]))((3[0-9]{3}[0-9]{4})|(9[0-9]{3}[0-9]{5}))$'); 
    return regex.test(phone);
}

var telefone = '31992399288';
validatePhone (telefone);
```

Nesse caso, o usuário digitar ou não os parênteses e o traço não vai modificar em nada o resultado do código já que ele limpa os caracteres que não são números de qualquer forma através do filtro do String.replace.

Comment: Onde eu utilizaria está expressão dentro do do Método @Marcos ?

Comment: Depende, você quer Validar ou Validar e Substituir o input pela mascara? Sinceramente, eu não sei javascript avançado o suficiente para explicar a validar e substituição simultânea, mas encontrei [um artigo](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/183-applying-masks-using-regular-expressions-in-javascript.htm) que parece tratar sobre isso

Comment: somente validar o numero

Comment: Se você quer só validar, pode fazer uma função qualquer dentro do seu escopo que aceita uma string como argumento e mandar retornar True ou False pra validar (o retorno de regex.test)

Comment: Beleza entendi, só mais uma duvida, eu preciso colocar a expressão que você critou entre / Expressão / correto? ou da forma que vc colocou está correto tbm?

Comment: Editei a resposta com um exemplo em forma de função.
Não precisa colocar entre / Expressao / porque o RegExp já monta uma expressão baseada em uma String fornecida.

Comment: Adicionei uma explicação do uso dos caracteres na expressão regular se tiver um pouco de interesse em entender seu uso :)

Comment: Eu entendi e já estou passando isto para meu sistema, só queria tirar um duvida com você sobre Expressões Regulares.
Minha duvida é a seguinte, nesta expressão que criou, você poderia me explicar o porque disto? (3[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}), eu entendi a primeiro dos números sequencias 0-9, esta que informei, você está fazendo algum calculo ou algo do tipo?, ou é só a separação do numero através do trasso ?

Comment: Os parênteses delimitam um escopo, uma sequência de caracteres que deve ser avaliada. Portanto, ( Expressão ) separa o que está de dentro do que está de fora.  3 [0-9]{3}  indica que vou validar o numero se começar com o caractere 3 e for seguidos de quaisquer outros 3 caracteres entre 0 e 9, portanto, 3000 e 3999. Após, o símbolo - indica que devo validar se após os 4 primeiros caracteres eu tiver um traço, e logo em seguida com [0-9]{4} valido se houverem mais 4 caracteres entre 0 e 9 em sequência (portanto, 0000 à 9999).

O resultado seria 3ddd-dddd (sendo d qualquer digito entre 0 e 9).

Comment: Se você quiser exemplos de cada um dos elementos da expressão que usei, o site Regexr que eu linkei no começo do post tem uma seção lateral que explica cada um e dá exemplos, é bem interessante e ajuda bastante quando surgem dúvidas.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76558/discussion-between-leonardo-macedo-and-marcos-de-andrade).