# Como verificar se um determinado número é de um telefone móvel?

Tags: algoritmo

Caros,

Após ler os comentários [**NESTE TÓPICO**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14343/como-diferenciar-tipos-de-telefone), datado em 2014, pergunto: *atualmente, para verificar se um número é de um telefone móvel, basta ler a string de trás pra frente, checando se o oitavo caractere é um número entre 6 e 9?*. Pois a regra pode ter mudado depois da inclusão do nono dígito nos telefones de SP.

Por favor, alguém sabe informar se isto está correto? Vou precisar fazer um app Android para exportação de contatos, que serão usados por um aplicativo de envios de SMS, portanto não serão permitidos a exportação de números de telefone fixo. A princípio o aplicativo será usado no Brasil.

Agradeço qualquer informação, ou até mesmo algum texto oficial da Anatel (não consegui encontrar no site deles) confirmando que essa regra continua a mesma agora em 2015!