# Campos não são 'mascarados' com jQuery Masked Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

Boa tarde,

@EDIT
Os campos agora estão acessíveis. Porém, o que é digitado não é mascarado conforme foi predefinido no script.

Plugin: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Cadastro</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(function($){
       $(".data").mask("99/99/9999");
       $(".telefone").mask("9999-9999");
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="">
    <div class="data">
        <label for="">Campo 1:</label>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="telefone">
        <label for="">Campo 2:</label>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="">
        <label for="">Campo 3:</label>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="">
        <label for="">Campo 4:</label>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="">
        <label for="">Campo 5:</label>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Como podem ver não entendo quase nada ainda. Estou começando a aprender.
Obrigado desde já!

Comment: O que queres dizer com _"impossíveis de serem acessados numa página PHP"_? queres dizer que não consegues receber o valor do input no servidor? ou que o input não funciona e o utilizador não consegue escrever nele? Podes colocar o HTML que tens?

Comment: @Sergio, não se consegue digitar nada no input, você clica dentro dele e tenta digitar mas nada é inserido.

Comment: Podes [edit] a pergunta e colocar o teu HTML? Se fizeres um jsFiddle é ideal...

Comment: Entao com certeza o problema não esta relacionado ao php. Você pode editar sua pergunta e colocar o codigo do formulario com os inputs também? Talvez ajude a encontrar o erro

Comment: Sergio e Andrei Coelho, editei.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás a aplicar o `.mask()` ao elemento `div`. Tens de aplicar ao elemento `input`. Assim o teu selector tem de ser `".classe_da_div input"`.

Assim funciona:

```
 jQuery(function ($) {
     $(".data input").mask("99/99/9999");
     $(".telefone input").mask("9999-9999");
 });
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/x94dzw92/

Comment: funcionou! Obrigado pela ajuda!!

Comment: @Luan ótimo! Bom que pude ajudar.

Comment: Gostei deste Plugin... Vou usar também! obrigado

Answer (score 0):

O código acima faz funcionar, mas para utilizar os dados do fomulário precisará colocar os atributos name e id dos campos input.

```
<div class="data"> 
    <label for="">Campo 1:</label>
    <input name="campo1" id="campo1" class="maskdata" type="text">
</div>
```

Na chamada função da máscara ainda pode fazer por herança ".data input" ou aplicação de classes com nomes à sua escolha como ".maskdata" ou ".masktel".

```
jQuery(function ($) {
     $(".data input, .maskdata").mask("99/99/9999");
     $(".telefone input, .masktel").mask("9999-9999");
 });
```

Segue exemplo rodando.
http://jsfiddle.net/s3vq3s9z/1/