# Trazer o valor de uma coluna de acordo com a condição de uma outra

Tags: sql, select

Estou desenvolvendo um script simples porém me deparei com uma situação que não estou conseguindo resolve-la, tentei através do CASE porém sem sucesso.

Com um select simples preciso trazer as colunas Nome, RG,CPF, **e o telefone CELULAR do cliente**, ai que está o problema, pois a estrutura da tabela encontra-se assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então, eu devo trazer o CONTATO 2 que é o contato correspondente a FORMA DE CONTATO de celular, no sistema estes campos são editaveis, então isso varia de cadastro para cadastro, tem registro que o contato 1 é o celular, em outros o 3 e assim por diante.

Então para exemplificar, meu select ficaria assim:

Nome, RG,CPF, CELULAR (E nessa coluna celular traria a coluna correspondente a FORMADECONTATO celular, que neste exemplo é o CONTATO2)

Agradeço a atenção e colaboração de todos.

Comment: Qual banco de dados?

Comment: O problema estava no meu CASE pessoal, foi resolvido. Obrigado!

Comment: Relacionado -> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14343/como-diferenciar-tipos-de-telefone